# Capybara is throwing error, but browser does it Ok

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

This test:

```
describe "Regions Management", type: :feature do

  feature "Editing a Region" do
    scenario "with valid parameters" do
      region = create(:region)
      visit edit_region_path(region)

      within "#edit_region_#{region.id}" do
        fill_in 'region_name', with: "Edited Region"
        click_button I18n.t('helpers.submit.update', model: Region.model_name.human)
        expect(current_path).to eql(region_path(region))
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Is failing with the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"regions", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

The region object does have an id:

```
[27, 36] in /home/leandro/projects/optimaster3/spec/features/regions_management_spec.rb
   27:       region = create(:region)
   28:       visit edit_region_path(region)
   29:       within "#edit_region_#{region.id}" do
   30:         fill_in 'region_name', with: "Edited Region"
   31:         byebug
=> 32:         click_button I18n.t('helpers.submit.update', model: Region.model_name.human)
   33: 
   34:         expect(current_path).to eql(region_path(region))
   35:       end
   36:     end
(byebug) region.reload
#<Region:0x000000099bba28>
(byebug) region.inspect
#<Region id: 27, name: "Region 26", ancestry: nil, notes: "Some notes", created_at: "2015-09-18 14:42:40", updated_at: "2015-09-18 14:42:40", parent_id: nil, lft: 1, rgt: 2, children_count: nil>
(byebug) click_button I18n.t('helpers.submit.update', model: Region.model_name.human)
*** ActionView::Template::Error Exception: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"regions", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

This is my routes.rb:

```
resources :regions do
  collection do
    get 'regions_list'
  end
end
```

I'm able to update a region on the browser, no problem. But when running the test this error is thrown.

This is the create test, and passes OK:

```
  feature "Creating a Region" do
    scenario "with valid parameters" do
      region = region_attributes = attributes_for(:region)
      visit new_region_path

      within "#new_region" do
        fill_in 'region_name', with: region_attributes[:name]
        fill_in 'region_notes', with: region_attributes[:notes]
        click_button I18n.t('helpers.submit.create', model: Region.model_name.human)
        expect(current_path).to eql(region_path)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: What's the output of `region = create(:region)` `puts region.inspect` ?  Looks like it doesn't have an ID.

Comment: It does have an id, already checked with byebug. Added it to the answer.

Comment: Did you try to manually edit a region? Does it fail too?

Comment: As I said: "I'm able to update a region on the browser, no problem". So, no, manually it doesn't fails.

Comment: Can you try to reload the region before click_button and than check its value?

Comment: Nothing, updated the answer with the output

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue, but it is strange you have the `expect` inside the `within` block. Does it make a difference if you move it outside?

Comment: I could, but the error is thrown when click method is called.

Comment: Since this is an ActioveView::Template::Error the error is being thrown when attempting to render the response template - so please show the update (I assume submitting to update) action from the controller and the view template.  Secondly you are using expect(current_path).to eql(...)   - this will work fine while you are using rack-test as your browser since everything is synchronous however if you switch to a JS capable driver will fail due to it being executed before the page has actually changed - if using Capy 2.5+ use  expect(page).to have_current_path(...) which has waiting behavior

Comment: can you show us the view code for the edit-region page (because that's what's trying to generate the url that's failing)